# If array key exists return its value

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I have an array called all_teams which contains the following

```
Array
(
    [33448] => Team1
    [33466] => Team2
    [33467] => Team3
    [33476] => Team4
    [33495] => Team5
)
```

I do a check within a `foreach` to check if `teamId` is in the array keys. If the array key exists I want to display the key's value.

So far I have

```
if(array_key_exists(intval($team['teamId']), $all_teams)) {
   echo 'set';
   // array key value needs to be here
} else {
   echo 'not set';
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `$all_teams[$intval($team['teamId'])]`? You basically want to access a value based on a key/index :)

Comment: `array_key_exists($team['teamId'],$all_teams)` try with this

Comment: If [`array_key_exists($team['teamId'], $all_teams)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) returns `TRUE` then `$all_teams[$team['teamId']]` is the value you need. Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @Terry you nailed it! Can't believe I missed something so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you simply want to access an array element's value by its index. It is as straightforward as doing `$all_teams[<<index>>]`, which is in this case the parsed `teamId`:

```
$teamId = intval($team['teamId']);
if(array_key_exists($teamId, $all_teams)) {
   echo $all_teams[$teamId];
} else {
   echo 'not set';
}
```

Comment: `(array_key_exists($teamId),` required two perameter